# Como enviar E-mail com formatação HTML no Windows Phone C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone

Olá, no Visual Studio 2012 tem o Objeto EmailComposeTask, mas ele não tem formatação HTML, gostaria de saber qual a melhor forma para enviar emails via Windows Phone com Formatação HTML.

Comment: De acordo com http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030764/send-html-content-via-emailcomposetask não tem como. @natanael-ribeiro-ferreira

Porém você pode tentar esta biblioteca: http://www.geekchamp.com/marketplace/components/livemailmessage

Veja também:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030764/send-html-content-via-emailcomposetask

Comment: Essa biblioteca vai resolver o meu problema, muito obrigado.

Comment: Favor marque como resposta. @natanael-ribeiro-ferreira

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acordo com [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030764/send-html-content-via-emailcomposetask) e a descrição da propriedade [EmailComposeTask.Body no MSDN:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.tasks.emailcomposetask.body(v=vs.105).aspx)

> The Body property does not support HTML formatting.

**Não tem como.**
**Porém** você pode utilizar este componente (pago): http://geekchamp.com/marketplace/components/livemailmessage 

 
 Veja uma solução alternativa (no primeiro link): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030764/send-html-content-via-emailcomposetask
Aqui um screenshot do do componente que permite inclusive anexo.
[image]

**Exemplo implementação:**

```
//create a new MailMessage object
MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
//set a Live/Hotmail or Gmail, or a custom SMTP account
mailMessage.UserName= "*****@hotmail.com ;                        // ****@gmail.com, ****@yourserver.com, etc.
mailMessage.Password = "********";
mailMessage.AccountType = accountType.MicrosoftAccount;   //you can set your  CustomSMTP server/port/no-ssl
mailMessage.From = "myapp@mycompany.com";
//set mail data
mailMessage.To = "foo@foo.com";
mailMessage.ReplyTo = "foo5@foo.com";
mailMessage.Cc= "foo0@foo.com;foo2@foo.com;foo3@foo.com";
mailMessage.Bcc= "foo4@foo.com;foo5@foo.com;foo6@foo.com";
mailMessage.Subject = "Hello from WP";
mailMessage.Body = "I can send any type of attachment from my app now !!";   **//text or HTML**
//attach ANY KIND of file from a resource or IsolatedStorage path
mailMessage.AddAttachment("\resources\file.jpg"); 
mailMessage.AddAttachment("\docs\file.pdf"); 
mailMessage.AddAttachment("\docs\file.xls");
mailMessage.AddAttachment("\rex\file.wav");
mailMessage.AddAttachment("\myFolder\file.mp3"); 
mailMessage.AddAttachment("\downloads\file.mp4"); 

//attach from in-memory data:
mailMessage.AddAttachment(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("yesssss".ToCharArray()), "memoryfile.txt");
//set message event handlers
mailMessage.Error +=  mailMessage_Error; 
mailMessage.MailSent += mailMessage_MailSent; 
mailMessage.Progress += mailMessage_Progress;  
//send email (async)
mailMessage.SendMail();
```

> Fontes:
>   
>   http://www.geekchamp.com/marketplace/components/livemailmessage
>   https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.tasks.emailcomposetask.body(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: HStack, Se possível edite a resposta e traga mais informações do motivo de não ser possível, [aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.tasks.emailcomposetask.body(v=vs.105).aspx) na seção *Remarks* têm algo sobre. Se não for pedir muito, poste um exemplo de uso da biblioteca mencionada ou algo alternativo. Dê uma olhada [Como faço para escrever uma boa resposta?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) também. =D

Comment: Ok, em breve vou atualizar a resposta. @QMechanic73

Comment: +1. Ficou melhor agora. =D

Comment: Obrigado @QMechanic73 :)